# JQuery selector

Tags: jquery, dom

Given the following unordered list, the JQuery selector `$("#root #2")` selects:

```
/ul/li/ul[@id='root']/li/ul[@id='1']/li/ul[@id='2']
```

Whereas I would have expected it to select the shorter path:

```
/ul/li/ul[@id='root']/li/ul[@id='2']
```

Anyone any ideas?

```
<ul>
    <li>root
        <ul id="root">
            <li>1
                <ul id="1">
                    <li>2
                        <ul id="2"> <!--*selecting this*-->
                            <li>3<ul id="3"></ul></li>          
                            <li>4<ul id="4"></ul></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>3<ul id="3"></ul></li>
                </ul>   
            <li>2
                <ul id="2"> <!-- *expecting this* -->                   
                    <li>3
                        <ul id="3"> 
                            <li>4<ul id="4"></ul></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>3<ul id="3"></ul></li>
            <li>4<ul id="4"></ul></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two reasons why the behavior might be undefined / not what you expect:

1. IDs are expected to be unique, and the path you receive precedes the path you want in the source.
2. (less likely in this situation) IDs are [expected to
   begin with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2)

Answer (score 2):

Using a space in a selector selects any ancestor.  My hunch is that since the li with id=2 comes before the ul with id=2 in the DOM, jQuery stops at that (since id's are expected to be unique).

I hope this isn't real HTML... because id's should really be unique.

Comment: -1 for not being more explicit about the unique IDs. No hunches involved here- using multiple IDs is plain wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the downvote.  Could you be more explicit as to what is so wrong with this answer from 2 years ago that it needs a downvote?  It seems to me that you're downvoting because you don't like the word "hunch", when in fact my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a descendant operator, which will search all descendants. I imagine that jQuery uses depth first search algorithm in searching the DOM tree. That explains why you get the longest one first. As for why jQuery only returns one node, you're using ID selector, which is supposed to be unique in all DOM node. I would expect jQuery to return after the first match, as there's no point in traversing the rest of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

This selector should return any element with an ID of 2 which is a descendant of any element with an ID of root, in DOM order. I'd expect it to return both of the elements you mentioned in your question. The deeper one will be first because it's first in the document.

Note that IDs should be unique. It is an error to have two elements with an ID of 2.